# What does the virtual network part of a VPN is used for?

Tags: vpn

So I’ve been studying VPN technologies lately.

There is still something I don’t really understand.

Let's say I'm a remote developer and I use VPN to access my company's svn servers and instant messaging service.

What is the point for a remote worker to appear to the local workers as if he was on the local network of the company ?

If a service of the local network is needed (for example the instant messaging system) can’t the admin just configure said service to go through the router and over the internet to get to the remote worker?

The conversation between the remote worker and the router can even be encrypted to prevent a Man-In-The-Middle attack.

I don't understand the need of a Virtual Network at this point.

Comment: "*The conversation beetween the remote worker and the routeur can even be encrypted*" remote computer builds encrypted tunnel to corporate router and authenticates through it: congratulations, you've just built a VPN.

Comment: @MadHatter Not necessarily. You could be using IPSec in transport mode (though you lose all the benefits of being on the corporate network, and have all the drawbacks of IPSec transport mode).

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I believe that IPSec in transport mode would not be best choice for end client connectivity, but it doesn't mean by any means that it is useless. Let's consider some protocol LDAPS/FTPS which may need sometimes multiple TLS handshakes in short time period. It's better (the latency) to strip it from TLS and push it via IPSec in case of server2server connectivity - no TLS handshakes for every new connection.

Comment: @MichaelHampton how is IPSec not a VPN?  Even in transport mode the payload is encrypted, and via PSK possession of the shared secret is how the remote node establishes its right to make a tunnel.  I'll be the first to admit that it's not a very *convenient* VPN, but I don't see that it's not one.

Comment: @MadHatter IPSec _is_ a VPN... in tunnel mode. In transport mode it's just authentication and encryption. That's no more a VPN than, say, TLS.

Comment: But there are some well-known TLS-based VPNs.  I think I see where you're going with this, I just think that definition of VPN might be a bit narrow.  For me (at least), anything that securely ties remote systems together over an insecure transport network at layer 3 (or lower) is a VPN.

Answer (score 2):

There are many uses for a VPN - but what you have said is true. You could configure that stuff to go over the internet to a remote worker. But:

- Then you have a critical service exposed to the internet
- Exposing it to the internet means drive-by script-kiddies will try to break into it
- You are potentially exposing your commercial-in-confidence company data to the internet (I have seen, personally, a case where a version control system leaked confidential company code onto the internet and got indexed by Google due to a bug that was released in an update)
- If the software you're exposing has a vulnerability you're putting it out there for the entire world
- Lots of software has no encryption
- Lots of in-house software has little to no authentication

Putting these kinds of services on the internet is irresponsible and dangerous unless you have an extremely well thought out security plan.

Requiring employees to use a VPN to access the services mitigates virtually all of those issues, and gives you some other bonuses (for example, 2FA authentication on the VPN).

There is a middle-ground, which is an application proxy (such as [Azure's App Proxy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-application-proxy-enable)) which expose services to the internet *only after* you have authenticated. These are gaining traction as they are lower-friction than a VPN.

Also, do you want your company file server to be exposed to the internet at wide? What about your accounting database? There is a lot of stuff that is best left segregated onto an internal network.

Comment: Okay so, using a VPN to access corporate servers data avoids risking using potentialy non-secure applications that would expose confidential data over the internet. For example, if I'm using a web server to give access to the company data to a remote worker, even through authentification and data encryption, it would be much more difficult to ensure the data security. Because VPN technologies are built around security whereas it's not web servers primary focus?

Comment: That, plus you end up having to build security into every single service.  While that's no bad idea, it's not good to rely on it: it only takes one stupid form served under HTTPS but with an HTTP post method (and I've seen them on e-commerce sites) to torpedo the plan.  Better to secure the entire tranport and sleep easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think Mark Henderson gave you good points, but I believe he has forgotten about the most important.

> If a service of the local network is needed (for example the instant messaging system) can’t the admin just configure said service to go through the router and over the internet to get to the remote worker ?

Sure he can, but let's face it, what is easier to maintain and more secure:

- look after multiple services (security vulnerabilities, certificates, multiple login attempts from whole wide word) which are most likely less secure than well formed VPN standards like IPSec/OpenVPN?
- setup VPN server and configure the client as one service which **will not** be also bullet prof forever without proper reconfiguration and maintenance.

Today you need SVN, tomorrow you will need SMB to access some other company documents, the day after you may want wake up your computer and work remotely via RDP. Then 10 other similar examples. Four words - your admin did all at once, he achieved: flexibility, scalability, security and authorization.

And by the way:

> The conversation between the remote worker and the router can even be encrypted to prevent MITM attack.

The [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655516/does-encryption-guarantee-integrity) was never designed to prevent MITM, the integrity mechanism is.

Answer (score 0):

VPN is accessible from anywhere ? it's secured already ? workers do not need to reconfigure anything about network because for them it looks like they are on the same LAN (even if they are in an other country/planet/world) ? You can manage who does what, how many has access and when, in a single place ?

I don't know which one is the most useful of these, but VPN is a great tool which would be invented if it didn't exist already.

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly, the main perk of being on a VLAN with the corporate servers for the remote worker is to avoid having to reconfigure anything when he goes out or when he gets back ? 

And there is a perk for the admin too becaue he/she does not have to handle several configurations per user access point but only one per user?